# Having problems with Nullable<T>

Tags: c#, xml, linq, nullable

I'm using LINQ and XDocument to parse an XML file. Some of the fields in the XML are not fixed, in that they could sometimes be a double or a string. Normally it will be a double but a string will indicate that the data was not available.

For example:

```
<current_observation>
    <temp_c>12.1</temp_c>
    <temp_c>NA</temp_c>
</current_observation>
```

I read in the XML fields and then set properties in a new object instance. Like this:

```
        var data = from i in weatherResponse.Descendants("current_observation")
                   select new CurrentConditions
                   {
                       // Attempt to parse. Set to null if not a double.
                       // This is one of the areas I'm having trouble with.
                       TemperatureC = Utilities.ParseDoubleValue(i.Element("temp_c"))

                       // If I use the following line instead then it works without problem.
                       // But this misses out all of the safe parsing.
                       // TemperatureC = (double)i.Element("temp_c")
                   };
```

I decided to use the `Nullable` type, so that I can use `TryParse` to either parse the field to a double, or if that was not possible set the property to a null.

Here is the code I'm using to try and parse the field:

```
    public static class Utilities
    {
        public static double? ParseDoubleValue(object inputValue)
        {
            if (inputValue == null)
                return null;

            double returnValue;

            return double.TryParse(inputValue.ToString(), out returnValue) ? returnValue : (double?)null;
        }
}
```

However, it seems that somewhere in my code it is not actually parsing the field properly, because if I do this:

```
    if(currentConditions.TemperatureC.HasValue)
        Console.WriteLine("Has a value: {0}", currentConditions.TemperatureC.Value);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Not Avaliable.");
```

Then HasValue will always return *false*.

**My question:** Why is my method of attempting to parse the value not working? Have I misunderstood the usage of `TryParse` and nullable types?

Comment: set some breakpoints and inspect the state of your code at various points

Comment: Your logic for ParseDoubleValue is a bit roundabout. You don't need the if block at the beginning since you already have the ternary operator, and you don't need to explicitly cast null to `double?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XElement` defines [explicit type conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986933%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the various numeric types.  Consequently, `(double)i.Element("temp_c")` is permitted and casts the [*value*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb303005%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the `XElement` to a double data type (via an internal call to `Double.Parse`).

When the `XElement` is passed as an argument of type `object` to your `Utilities.ParseDoubleValue` method, you are passing the entire `XElement`.  The call to `inputValue.ToString()` returns not `12.1`, but rather `<temp_c>12.1</temp_c>`, [the indented XML value for the node](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341005%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  And `double.TryParse("<temp_c>12.1</temp_c>")` will, of course, fail.

The error rests in that you most likely want to provide this method with the string value of the `XElement`, rather than the XElement itself. This is a simple matter of changing:

```
TemperatureC = Utilities.ParseDoubleValue(i.Element("temp_c"))
```

to

```
TemperatureC = Utilities.ParseDoubleValue(i.Element("temp_c").Value)
```

Second, as a defensive measure, you may want to reconsider the method signature for your method:

```
public static double? ParseDoubleValue(object inputValue)
```

This will accept any object, but you are ultimately interested in converting a string that the caller provides.  Changing it to accept only a string will ensure that callers provide a string, and failure to do so will result in a compilation error.

```
public static double? ParseDoubleValue(string inputValue)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Also, your detailed answer helped me understand it in much more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

i.Element returns an XElement, not the value.  And, of course, this isn't going to be parseable to a number.  You need `i.Element("temp_c").Value`